# How to change relative paths of files when deploying project

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, filepath, executable-jar

This is my project structure:

[image]

[image]

When I execute my programm inside netbeans I load the xosc files using this path:

```
XMLReaderWriter.getXMLDocument("./src/Vorlagen/OpenScenario/OS_TemplateVTD.xosc");
```

This is the functions from my XMLReaderWriter:

```
public static Document getXMLDocument(String absoluteFileName) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File(absoluteFileName)); //parse odr file into document
    return document;
}
```

And it works because I work inside the project. But after I deploy the project and execute the jar file I get this error:

[image]

The problem is that when I execute the jar file, it tries to load files from the "dist" order instead of the actuall folder. How can I deploy the files inside the dist order in order to access the files wen I execute the jar file?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

Comment: What is XMLReaderWriter?  Is that a class you wrote?  If so, edit your question and show the source of the getXMLDocument method.

Comment: @VGR yes I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

`./src/Vorlagen/OpenScenario/OS_TemplateVTD.xosc` is a relative path starting from current folder. And because you start project in Netbeans current folder is root folder of the project.

So there are several options:

1. Pack that file into jar as a classpath resource

   ```
   InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + filename);
   Document document = documentBuilder.parse(in);
   ```
2. Set an property with full path to file (let's name it `pathToConfig`), start java with `-DpathToConfig=/full/path/to/file` and then in Java use value from that property

   ```
   String filename = System.getProperty("pathToConfig");
   ```

And if you use Maven it is better to align your directories structure to Maven's standard layout (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

If you place your file into `src\main\resources` it will be packed inside jar automatically. And path to that file which should be used I relative to `src\main\resources`. Like if you use `src\main\resources\vorlagen\openScenario\OS_TemplateVTD.xosc` then in your java code you need to use `vorlagen\openScenario\OS_TemplateVTD.xosc`

Comment: how to pack the file into the jar as a classpath resource. I get null for the inputstream as the "getResourceAsStream" method can't find my file